# accessing Link server with Different user

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL2008 with window log in. I have to access a table from link server for which I have a user with read permission. Can I access link server with this user?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new **`user login`**

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin link_server_name, 'FALSE', NULL, username , password
```

**[MSDN Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)**

Comment: we use [linkServer].[DB].dbo.Table to access Table so cant we use username in this?

Comment: No. The user from which you **`login`** must have the rights. So it will implicitly mention the username.